# AppleScript to detect when an accessibility setting has been changed

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write a script that will alert me whenever my reduce transparency setting has been changed so I can get a better idea of what application might be changing it.

I am able to manually open system preferences and toggle the setting with an AppleScript but I can not read the setting and I cant do this without actually opening a new window.

I have seen [this](http://tell%20application%20%22System%20Events%22%20%20tell%20appearance%20preferences%20%20get%20properties%20%20--%3E%20returns:%20%7Bscroll%20arrow%20placement:together,%20font%20smoothing%20limit:4,%20recent%20applications%20limit:10,%20scroll%20bar%20action:jump%20to%20next%20page,%20double%20click%20minimizes:true,%20recent%20servers%20limit:10,%20appearance:blue,%20recent%20documents%20limit:10,%20highlight%20color:%7B46516,%2054741,%2065535%7D,%20class:appearance%20preferences%20object,%20smooth%20scrolling:false,%20font%20smoothing%20style:automatic%7D%20%20set%20properties%20to%20%7Bscroll%20arrow%20placement:together%20at%20top%20and%20bottom,%20font%20smoothing%20limit:4,%20recent%20applications%20limit:10,%20scroll%20bar%20action:jump%20to%20here,%20double%20click%20minimizes:true,%20recent%20servers%20limit:20,%20appearance:blue,%20recent%20documents%20limit:20,%20highlight%20color:%7B0,%200,%2032000%7D,%20smooth%20scrolling:true,%20font%20smoothing%20style:light%7D%20%20end%20tell%20end%20tell) tutorial which goes over how to do various preferences scripts however it does not show anything for accessibility settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option.   This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
property resultValue : missing value
property originalValue : missing value

tell application "System Preferences"
    tell its pane "Accessibility"
        reveal anchor "Seeing_Display"
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events"
            set originalValue to get value of checkbox "Reduce transparency" of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
            set resultValue to originalValue
            repeat while resultValue is equal to originalValue
                delay 1
                set resultValue to get value of checkbox "Reduce transparency" of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit

display notification with title ¬
    "REDUCE TRANSPARENCY HAS CHANGED"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might take some investigative work and patience.  Firstly, let me tell you how to read and set the *reduce transparency* setting using AppleScript:

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell property list file "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist" to ¬
        tell property list item "reduceTransparency"
            get its value -- returns true or false
            set its value to (not result) -- switch its setting
        end tell
```

The `get` and `set` commands do what you expect they would.  Of course, you can substitute `(not result)` for specific values of either `true` or `false`.

As far as I know, there's no way for AppleScript to monitor a systems setting in the fashion you're after.  It's not really designed for that purpose, although Cocoa-AppleScripting can achieve a bit more with regards to event listening.

BUT, there's actually a *Terminal* command builtin to MacOS called `opensnoop` which "tracks  file opens. As a process issues a file open, details such as UID, PID and pathname are printed out." (*Quoted from the man page.*)

This is where the investigative part will have to happen.

Run `sudo opensnoop` (then enter your admin password) and it will print out file accesses as and when they occur along with lots of pertinent information regarding that access (process ID, the name of the application requesting access, etc.).  This might overload you with lots of useless information regarding files you don't care about, and a bunch of *DTrace* errors (I believe these result from MacOS's *System Integrity Protection* which prevents some protected files from being read by DTrace).

So you could try using the flag `-f` or `-n` to specify a specific file (f) or specific process (n) you want to monitor, e.g.

```
    sudo opensnoop -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist
```

However, it's hard to say for certain what file or process you ought to be watching (after all, it's the process that you're trying to uncover as the guilty party).

So, you might end up having to overload yourself with a naked `sudo opensnoop` call, the output of which I suggest you write to a text file.  Not only will this eliminate any *DTrace* errors in the final result (though these will still appear in the *Terminal* window itself, but don't worry about it), it will give you a chance to comb over it later and search it for relevant terms and see what comes up.

To do this, run this command:

```
    sudo opensnoop > ~/Downloads/snoop.txt
```

which will write all the data to *snoop.txt* (I've elected to have it saved in the *Downloads* folder just in case you have your *Desktop* and *Documents* folder shared through iCloud—the text file will be continuously amended for as long as *opensnoop* is left to run, which means it would be continuously uploading to iCloud as well).

To terminate the running of *opensnoop*, return to the *Terminal* window (which must remain open through this, although you can minimise it), and press Ctrl-C.  Then type `exit`, hit return, and quit *Terminal*.

I can't guarantee this will definitely solve your mystery, but I do hope it helps in some way.

Comment: I just came by [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application) question from a few years back regarding the monitoring of file access.  It has several answers detailing various techniques by which to go about it.

Comment: Why did I get deducted 15 points for this ?  There’s no feedback available.

Comment: FYI The reason your reputation took a 15 point hit is because J.Doe decided to mark a different answer as the accepted answer. Note that your answer no longer has the green check mark and another answer does. Have a look at: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)